# Action method that returns FilePath is not working some times. Why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public FilePathResult GetImage(string user)
{
    var path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "files\\uploads\\users\\" + user + "\\avatar\\";
    var ext = this.GetImageExtension(path, user);
    return ext != null ? File(path + user + "." + ext, "image/" + ext, user + "." + ext) : File(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "files\\commonFiles\\users\\avatar\\noavatar.png", "image/png", "noavatar.png");
}
```

And inside my views I have this:

```
<img src="/MyAccount/GetImage/?user=@User.Identity.Name" 
     alt="@User.Identity.Name" />
```

Now, whenever I use this inside my web developer server it works perfectly ok. But when I publish my site on my server, it is not even trying to hit that action. Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why?

Because you have hardcoded the url to your controller action instead of using an url helper:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "MyAccount", new { user = User.Identity.Name })" alt="@User.Identity.Name" />
```

You should never hardcode urls in an ASP.NET MVC application but always use url helpers.

Also passing the currently logged in user as query string parameter looks like a horrible security issue. There's nothing preventing the user from passing whatever username he likes and *consulting* the images of that user. You should read the currently authenticated user in your controller action.

So start by getting rid of this query string parameter:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "MyAccount")" alt="@User.Identity.Name" />
```

and then in your controller action you could always retrieve the currently logged in user with the `User.Identity.Name` property:

```
[Authorize]
public FilePathResult GetImage()
{
    string user = User.Identity.Name;
    var path = Server.MapPath(
        string.Format("~/files/uploads/users/{0}/avatar/", user)
    );
    var ext = this.GetImageExtension(path, user);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ext))
    {
        return File(
            Server.MapPath("~/files/commonFiles/users/avatar/noavatar.png"), 
            "image/png", 
            "noavatar.png"
        );
    }
    var file = Path.ChangeExtension(Path.Combine(path, user), ext);
    return File(file, "image/" + ext, user + "." + ext);
}
```

I've also decorated this controller action with the `[Authorize]` attribute to make it accessible only to authenticated users. If this is not your case you could still keep the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute but check for `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` before attempting to access his username.

Comment: Actually, the problem was, because i am dumb - when i published this site it didn't copy all my working directories - and it was crashing out. Anyways your comment is great and i was missing that too. Thanks!

Comment: I have also updated my answer to include information about passing the currently logged in username in the query string being a very bad idea.